# Creating dynamic post deploy doc with Ansible

Tags: ansible

The idea is to use "debug" module or something similar to generate post-build doc with Ansible.
Something like

```
Your servers are ready:
server1 192.168.1.1
Role: web server
Packages installed and configured:
-php
-apache
server2 192.168.1.2
Role: database
...
```

Note how the output is multiline and will use ansible variables and possibly blocks.
What would be the best way to implement this? I was thinking of a mix of includes, "debug" module use, jinja template for the text above etc.

Comment: You would likely need to write your own version of ansible-playbook, which is basically just a python script that loads the inventory, loads your playbook, then runs the playbook and outputs the results to the screen.  Rather than output to the screen it sounds like you'd need to collect the results, organize them, then output what you want.  Trying to do this entirely from within a playbook by using includes, etc. would likely become overly complex and difficult to maintain.

Comment: @BruceP, it could be worth a possible answer given a bit more details/links. For something simple so far I have settled on: debug msg with | (for multiline output), custom callback plugin (to display new lines properly below json output), includes to the doc yaml in cookbooks that need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible with Ansibles [callback plugins](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#callbacks). A callback plugin can define handlers for various actions. These actions include completed/failed tasks and playbook completion, which should be all you need. (but there are way more)

Unfortunately plugins are not documented. You need to learn from the [existing callbacks](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback) and lots of debugging.